# Problems with $ref between parent and child component

Tags: vue.js

I'm using dynamic forms to break up a long form.  Beneath each dynamic form are two action buttons which, when clicked, send the user back one form set or onto the next one (unless the end of the form has been reached - the 'Next' button is replaced by a 'Submit' button).

As I have three different forms that all use the same action buttons, I decided to create a child component ('ActionButtons') for action buttons - and in doing so I've gone from code that worked to code that doesn't.

Specifically, I'm having problems with `ref` information involved in controlling the 'Next' button.  The error message is `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$v' of undefined"`

The code that worked fine (i.e. before I created 'ActionButtons') is:

```
<template>
    ...
    <keep-alive>
        <component
            ref="currentStep"
            :is="currentStep"
            @update="processStep"
            :wizard-data="formvars"
        ></component>
    </keep-alive>
    ...
    <button
        @click="nextButtonAction"
        :disabled="!canGoNext"
        class="btn"
    >{{isLastStep ? 'Submit' : 'Next'}}</button>
    ...
</template>

<script>

  import Gap2InputInfo from './Gap2InputInfo'
  import Gap2Materials from './Gap2Materials'

  export default {
    name: 'GAP2Form',
    components: {
      Gap2InputInfo,
      Gap2Materials
    },
    data () {
      return {
        currentStepNumber: 1,
        canGoNext: false,
        wizardData: {},
        steps: [
          'Gap2InputInfo',
          'Gap2Materials',
        ],
        formvars: {
          id: 0,
          purchase: null,
          name: null,
          quantity: null,
          supplier: null,
          nsteps: 0
        },
        updatedData: null
      }
    },
    computed: {
      isLastStep () {
        return this.currentStepNumber === this.length
      },
      length () {
        this.formvars.nsteps = this.steps.length;
        return this.steps.length
      },
      currentStep () {
        return this.steps[this.currentStepNumber - 1];
      },
    },
    methods: {
      nextButtonAction () {
        if (this.isLastStep) {
          this.submitForm()
        } else {
          this.goNext()
        }
      },
      processStep (step) {
        Object.assign(this.formvars, step.data);
        this.canGoNext = step.valid
      },
      goBack () {
        this.currentStepNumber--;
        this.canGoNext = true;
      },
      goNext () {
        this.currentStepNumber++;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.canGoNext = !this.$refs.currentStep.$v.$invalid
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In creating the child component, I send the following props to the child

```
<action-buttons :currentStepNumber="currentStepNumber" :canGoNext="canGoNext" :isLastStep="isLastStep" :currentStep="currentStep"></action-buttons>
```

and have moved the methods associated with the button actions from the parent to the child component.

My child component is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="actions" class="buttons">
      <button
          @click="goBack"
          v-if="mcurrentStepNumber > 1"
          class="btn-outlined"
      >{{$t('back')}}
      </button>
      <button
          @click="nextButtonAction"
          :disabled="!canGoNext"
          class="btn"
      >{{isLastStep ? 'Submit' : 'Next'}}</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {required} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
  export default {
    name: "ActionButtons",
    props: ['currentStepNumber','canGoNext','isLastStep','currentStep'],
    data: function () {
      return {
        mcurrentStepNumber: this.currentStepNumber,
        mcurrentStep: this.currentStep,
        mcanGoNext: this.canGoNext,
        misLastStep: this.isLastStep
        }
    },
    methods: {
      nextButtonAction () {
        if (this.misLastStep) {
          this.submitForm()
        } else {
          this.goNext()
        }
      },
      goBack () {
        this.mcurrentStepNumber--;
        this.mcanGoNext = true;
      },
      goNext () {
        this.mcurrentStepNumber++;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.mcanGoNext = !this.$refs.currentStep.$v.$invalid    **** Error triggered at this line
        })
      }

    }
  }
</script>
```

Now when I click the 'Next' button, I get the `Cannot read property '$v' of undefined` error message. If I've interpreted it correctly, it cannot read the $refs data.  I tried altering the code in the child component to

```
this.mcanGoNext = !this.$parent.$refs.currentStep.$v.$invalid
```

but the outcome remained the same.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve; the approach you've taken isn't idiomatic Vue. (Props down and events up.) It's definitely introducing some really tight coupling between components, something that most code tries to avoid. Perhaps if you could take a step back and explain the problem you want to solve, it would be possible to suggest a more appropriate strategy.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't explained the situation properly - it's always difficult to find a balance between conciseness and overburdening folks with detail and obviously I've not got that balance right here. But I am running props down (from the parent to the child - actionbuttons -  component).  I'll review my problem description nevertheless. Cheers/Tom

Comment: I think you are missing a `ref` attribute!

Comment: I see that the code is passing some props to the child component, but why not emit events to the parent (e.g. `"next"` and `"prev"` events)? And why is the child storing local copies of props from the parent? (E.g. with `canGoNext` and `mcanGoNext` what value is the latter adding?)